# wget blurry image and dropdown

Tags: web-scraping, download, web-crawler, wget

Hi im trying to download single page and 1 deep pages.

So i tried this command;

`wget --user-agent=" Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" --level=1 --span-hosts --wait=3 --timestamping --page-requisites https://www.blabla.com`

Its downloaded blurry images and didnt work dropdown menus. Can someone help me about wget or another scraping method for download.(with python script or another. httrack didnt work)

"........%2Fimages%2Fillustrations%2Flearning-illustration-black-history-month-01.png?auto=format&blur=200&h=650&ixlib=php-3.3.1&px=16&s=ab1fec484ae1d53fb9750018152aa0d9"

I think blurry because pics have this link when i downloaded.